# Flutter white screen in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I added flutter as a module to my existing app and the starting activity of the app is a subclass of `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity`.

This is very weird but in debug mode everything works as expected but in release mode I see a white screen with the following log flooded

```
[DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
```

I tried monitoring flutter logs using `flutter logs` but they do not show anything, which it should because I have added print statements to my `main` method.

I tried adding the following to the release config

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

But still nothing. I am using flutter 2.10.5.

Flutter activity entry in my manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainFlutterActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please try to run with flutter run -v --profile command see the logs for details. as profile mode is close to Release mode

Comment: The issue is that I have added flutter as a module to my app, so I have to run the app using Android Studio. Flutter run command does not work

Comment: Have you looked into specifying the theme in the manifest? What do you have set for your metadata. Can you post the full XML for the manifest?